# Highlight specific rows in table according to condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying make this macro works. It supposed to highlight rows in a table according to the condition. When I try to offset the selected range, so only the cells within the table get highlighted. But when I do so, my condition doesnt work as it should be. I am completly newbie to this, many thanks for any advice.

```
Sub výklep()

'Find the last non-blank cell in column
LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set SelectedRange = Range("I6:I" & LastRow)

For Each cell In SelectedRange
    If cell.Value > 10 Then cell.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 9)).Offset(1, -7).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Would conditional formatting be simpler?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do if a cell in Column I >10, let's say Cell I7, then what cells in row 7 do you want to change the cell color ?

Comment: And you should be getting an error trying to offset `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 9)).Offset(1, -7)` , offsetting column 1 by -7 is -6, and should result in an Error

Answer (score 0):

You must be careful while offsetting with minus sign (-). In your case it is minus seven (-7). While looping it is crossing the left border of your sheet thus causing error.